Underground/Buried Service for RV
I need to run 120V/30 Amp line to a new RV pad on my property in Texas. There is a meter box location approximately 40 feet from the pad.  I am planning to run 10 gauge wires, underground from the meter box, to a new post with RV outlet at the pad.  My questions are:
If I run underground conduit, I was planning on 3/4" PVC, 18" underground.  What is the correct/preferred wire to use?  10/2 w/g UB wire, or individual wires (THWN)?
If I use the individual wires, should I use solid core or multi-strand?
This is actually my son's property, and he is wanting to use a box at the RV that only contains the 30 amp outlet.  My preference is to use a box that includes the outlet and either a 30Amp breaker, or switch.  We will have a 30 amp breaker at the meter box for this application.

Yes, you should definitely have a switch at the pedestal (which usually ends up being a circuit breaker). It's safe to open the switch under load; you don't want to be unplugging the cord under load. 30A can make a big spark.

Thanks,  My thoughts, exactly.  I believe we need access to the shut-off at the pedestal.

Consider running 6-6-6-6 aluminum.   It is comparable to #8 but a lot cheaper.  You'll thank me later when you get a larger RV that can take 50A.

Definitely wires (THWN) in conduit. Much easier than pulling cable.
You may want to consider running 8 AWG wire instead of 10 AWG wire. Why? If you then add one more wire (so 3 x 8 AWG + 1 x 10 AWG (ground) instead of 3 x 10 AWG) then you can provision up to 50A @ 240V. Which lets you use one of these RV panels:

There are various combinations available, but typical is a 50A subpanel with 50A 240V (for large RVs or EV charging with an appropriate "travel charger"), 30A 120V (what you are currently planning on installing) and 20A 120V (a regular receptacle for tools or whatever else you need to plug in, whether an RV is hooked up or not).
With conduit you could also run 10 AWG wire now and upgrade later - 3/4" is just big enough to make it work with 8 AWG.

Or at the very least, run an extra #8 and feed https://www.homedepot.com/p/Connecticut-Electric-30-Amp-RV-Power-Outlet-with-Branch-Breakers-CESMPSC41GRHR/100669963 (providing an extra 20A duplex receptacle)

Thanks to all for the help and guidance.  It is greatly appreciated.

Came here to write this answer. Perfection!
